# EF Relationship (1 to 0..1) won't be removed

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a Code First model in Entity Framework version 6.1.1 that basically looks like this:

```
public class TinMan {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Heart Heart { get; set; }
}

public class Heart {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

This is represented in an actual database like this, where the `Heart_Id` column is generated automatically by EF which also creates the foreign key relationship between the two tables:

```
TinMen:                 Hearts:

Id    Heart_Id          Id
1     1                 1
2     3                 2
3     NULL              3
```

Creating a relation where none exist, or changing an existing relation works just fine:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
    TinMan bill = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 1);
    if (bill != null) bill.Heart = 2;
    TinMan bob = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 3);
    if (bob != null) bob.Heart = 1;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now I try to remove a relation:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext()) {
    TinMan jebediah = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 2);
    if (jebediah != null) jebediah.Heart = null;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

After this has been executed TinMan with ID==2 *still* has a Heart in the database, i.e. it was **not** set to `NULL` in the database.

Why?

Comment: This doesn't explain why setting the navigation property to `null` doesn't work, but please note that without additional configuration, EF will consider `one-to-many` relation from `Heart` to `TinMan`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    TinMan jebediah = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 2);
    context.Entry(jebediah).Reference(t => t.Heart).CurrentValue = null;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is an alternate way of doing it, based on my comment:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    TinMan jebediah = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 2);
    context.Entry(jebediah).Reference(t => t.Heart).Load();
    jebediah.Heart = null;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

In any case, this is a scenario where having an explicit foreign key property (ex. `public int? HeartId { get; set; }` can be advantageous. With a foreign key property, you can remove a relationship without pre-loading the related entity. For example:

```
using (MyDbContext dbContext = new MyDbContext())
{
    TinMan jebediah = dbContext.TinMen.FirstOrDefault(man => man.Id == 2);
    jebediah.HeartId = null;
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This is kinda what I was looking into at the time of your answer. I tried it and it worked. Any idea why just setting the property to `null` doesn't work?

Comment: When you load the `TinMan` entity from the database, the related `Heart` doesn't get loaded yet, because lazy loading is enabled. So when you set it to `null` at that point, nothing's really happening as far as EF is concerned. Setting the related `Heart` to `null` will work _if_ it was loaded beforehand. I updated my answer (included an example).